# JavaScript Code-Splitting with hiding the code-endpoints

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bundle, bundling-and-minification, code-splitting

hey im not really familar with JavaScript or react.
So i hope i dont a too easy question:

i want to have a "one-page"-website, and want to change this page dynamically with ajax-request.

I have coded for example code for four visibility-levels (guest-user, normal user, moderator, administrator)

if you log in into my page and you are an admin, you get the JS-Code from all levels. For example in the json-response there is a list with URLs to the Javascriptcode destination.

If you log in as a normal user you should get only the normal-user js-code. The guest-user-js-code you already have; you got that at the time you entered the page.

So i guess the thing is clear, what i want.

But how i should implement this? 
Are there some ready solutions out there?

https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html
maybe i have to adjust this here?

and maybe there are some good bundlers out there, that i can use, doing that splitting with hiding the endpoint urls (which i get if i have the rights from an ajax-request)?

lg knotenpunkt

Comment: Your question is too broad.

Comment: hm why you thinks so?
im looking only for a solution splitting js-code into different "files" and secure the access to them. Maybe there is a automatic solution out there or some technique easily achieving this with a few configuration-stuff of bundlers

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, I think that the question is very, very broad. Each one of the requests is a full standalone argument.

Generally speaking, I hope that this will led you to the right way.

You can split your code by using CommonJS or ES6 modules (read more [here](https://medium.com/computed-comparisons/commonjs-vs-amd-vs-requirejs-vs-es6-modules-2e814b114a0b)). That is to keep it "modular". Then, during the bundling process, other splitting techniques may be applied, but this will depend on your development environment and used tools.

Your best option for bundling would be [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org) without any doubt. However, directly dealing with Webpack or setting up a custom development environment is not an easy task. You'll certainly want to read about [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev), which is a good place to start for a Single Page Application. It will allow you to write your code in a "modular" fashion and will bundle, split and process it automatically (uses Webpack under the hood).

Finally securing access must be done server-side (there is another world of available options there).

Comment: thats clear, i dont allow the user doing something, on what he is not allowed (in the backend)
But i also want to secure my code. i dont want let the user see, which "view"-code/features the admin have.